# Scraper To Copy Articles In Bulk

Tags: python, web-scraping, artificial-intelligence, large-data, bulk

I'm working on an AI project, and one of the steps is to get ~5,000 articles from an online outlet.

I'm a beginner programmer, so please be kind. I've found a site that is very easy to scrape from, in terms of URL structure - I just need a scraper that can take an entire article from a site (we will be analyzing the articles in bulk, with AI).

The div containing the article text for each piece, is the same across the entire site - "col-md-12 description-content-wrap".

Does anyone know a simple Python script that would simply go thru a .CSV of URLs, pull the text from the above listed ^ div of each article, and output it as plain text? I've found a few solutions, but none are 100% what I need.

Ideally all of the 5,000 articles would be outputted in one file, but if they need to each be separate, that's fine too. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I did something a little bit similar to this about a week ago.  Here is the code that I came up with.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from pandas import DataFrame

resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.cnbc.com/finance/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))
substring = 'https://www.cnbc.com/'

df = ['review']
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
#print(link['href'])
if (link['href'].find(substring) == 0): 
# append
df.append(link['href'])

#print(link['href'])


#list(df)
# convert list to data frame
df = DataFrame(df)
#type(df)
#list(df)

# add column name
df.columns = ['review']


from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
df['sentiment'] = df['review'].apply(lambda x: sid.polarity_scores(x))
def convert(x):
if x < 0:
return "negative"
elif x > .2:
return "positive"
else:
return "neutral"
df['result'] = df['sentiment'].apply(lambda x:convert(x['compound']))
df['result']

df_final = pd.merge(df['review'], df['result'], left_index=True, right_index=True)
df_final

df_final.to_csv('C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\out.csv')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this is scraping the URLs. What I'm looking for takes the text of an article (found in the field I listed in my original post). So, for example, it would take a Buzzfeed article (the writing itself), and dump it into a file. The trick is I'm looking to do this on a large scale, so I can use the text to train an AI.